# problems with perform segue with multiple states on a UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have a UITableView that has two states. One when the user is logged in and the other is when the user is logged out. Both show different details. How do I set up the tableview so that when the user selects something in the tableview it goes to that designated view controller. Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

    class SideTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



        @IBOutlet weak var loggout: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var dismissButton: UIButton!

        var loggedIn = ["Find Event", "Create Event", "Past Events", "Recently Viewed", "Help", "Setting"]

        var loggedOut = ["Log In", "Find Event", "Create Event", "Help"]


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            dismissButton.layer.cornerRadius =
            dismissButton.frame.size.width / 2
            loggout.layer.cornerRadius =
            loggout.frame.size.width / 2
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                loggout.isHidden = false
                print("User Signed In, Showing Relivent Info")

            } else {
                loggout.isHidden = true
                print("User Not Logged In, Showing Relivent Info")
            }
            tableview.reloadData()
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                // User is signed in.
                return loggedIn.count

            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                return loggedOut.count
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                // User is signed in.
                cell.textLabel?.text = loggedIn[indexPath.item]
                return cell

            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                cell.textLabel?.text = loggedOut[indexPath.item]
                return cell
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                //performSegue(withIdentifier: "tologinfrommain", sender: nil)
        }
```

Comment: Rather than triggering the segue using an action connector in the storyboard, you will need to perform the appropriate segue in `didSelectRowAt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two static arrays of desired segues for logged in and logged out states like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var loggout: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var dismissButton: UIButton!

        var loggedIn = ["Find Event", "Create Event", "Past Events", "Recently Viewed", "Help", "Setting"]

        var loggedOut = ["Log In", "Find Event", "Create Event", "Help"]

satatic var loggedInSegues = ["FindEventSegue", "CreateEventSegue", "PastEventSegue", "RecentlyViewedSegue", "HelpSegue", "SettingsSegue"]

static var loggedOutSegues = ["LogInSegue", "FindEventSegue", "CreateEventSegue", "HelpSegue"]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            dismissButton.layer.cornerRadius =
            dismissButton.frame.size.width / 2
            loggout.layer.cornerRadius =
            loggout.frame.size.width / 2
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                loggout.isHidden = false
                print("User Signed In, Showing Relivent Info")

            } else {
                loggout.isHidden = true
                print("User Not Logged In, Showing Relivent Info")
            }
            tableview.reloadData()
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                // User is signed in.
                return loggedIn.count

            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                return loggedOut.count
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                // User is signed in.
                cell.textLabel?.text = loggedIn[indexPath.item]
                return cell

            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                cell.textLabel?.text = loggedOut[indexPath.item]
                return cell
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil  {
                performSegue(withIdentifier:loggedInSegues[indexPath.row], sender: nil)
            } else {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: loggedOutSegues[indexPath.row], sender: nil)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Row #\((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)")

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! popTableViewCell
     if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
    if  cell.textLabel?.text! == "Find Event"{
        print(loggedIn[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutofind", sender: nil)
    }
    else if cell.textLabel?.text! == "Create Event"{
        print(loggedIn[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutocreate", sender: nil)
    }
    else if cell.textLabel?.text! == "Past Events" {
        print(loggedIn[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutopast", sender: nil)
    }
    else if cell.textLabel?.text! == "Recently Viewed" {
        print(loggedIn[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutorv", sender: nil)
    }
    else if cell.textLabel?.text! == "Help" {
        print(loggedIn[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutohelp", sender: nil)
    }
    else if cell.textLabel?.text! == "Setting" {
        print(loggedIn[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutosetting", sender: nil)
    }
}
     else {

    if cell.textLabel?.text! == "Log In" {
performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutologin", sender: nil)
}
else if  cell.textLabel?.text! == "Find Event" {
performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutofind", sender: nil)
}
else if  cell.textLabel?.text! == "Create Event" {
performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutocreate", sender: nil)
}
else if  cell.textLabel?.text! == "Help" {
performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutohelp", sender: nil)
}

    }

}
```

By this you can perform a Segue to your desired VC.

Hope it helps.

Comment: when I select something it will always take me to the first performSegue. How do i fix it?

Comment: Hi @JameelMaqbool You simply Remove the line if it is none of Your Use. i also updated the Answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @JameelMaqbool is it Worked?

Comment: Please look at my answer below and see what code I have. I still dont understand why its not working. Thanks

Comment: @JameelMaqbool please have a look as i updated the tested Ans hope it will work. As you need

Comment: Maybe guard let the cell.text and switch on it instead of if else chaining all the values. That will make the code way more readable.